# Find time difference between highest and lowest value in data frame and sort by factor

Tags: r, posixct

I have a data frame and it looks like this:

```
submition_id       time_answered
           2 2017-11-06 14:19:30
           2 2017-11-06 14:22:45
           2 2017-11-06 14:24:55
           2 2017-11-06 14:34:10
           4 2017-11-06 14:31:23
           4 2017-11-06 14:33:21
           5 2017-11-06 14:54:48
           5 2017-11-06 14:59:38 
           5 2017-11-06 15:05:39
         ...                 ...
```

So basically my submition_id column is a factor column and time_answered column is POSIXct column. I want to find the time difference for each factor which is basically max(x) - min(x). How can I do this effective with inbuilt functions? Such that I get

```
submition_id       difference
           2            14.67
           4             1.96
           5             9.77
         ...              ...
```

I would like it in minutes as well.

Comment: You can use `aggregate` with `difftime` to find the difference between highest and lowest time grouped by 'submittion_id'  Or `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(submition_id) %>% summarise(difference = difftime(min(time_answered), max(time_answered), unit = 'min'))`

Comment: Please use `dput()` to show your data!

Comment: My data won't fit in here, I wish I could

Comment: @arezaie you can just save the first 10 rows of your data as another dataframe and post that one. No need for the whole dataset :-)

Comment: structure(list(submition_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), time_answered = structure(c(1509974370, 1509974372, 1509974378, 1509974381, 1509975107, 1509975110, 1509975112, 1509975217, 1509975217, 1509975221, 1509975226, 1509975229, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("submition_id", "time_answered" ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

Comment: Well @akrun code worked almost. I had to switch to order of min and max since it would give me negative values otherwise

Comment: Yeah, it should be that way.  I didn't test the code

Comment: Why the downvote? Was a perfectly fine question

Comment: Probably because no research and no attempt to solve the problem was made. See the [ask] page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there must be similar questions on SO.

However, for the sake of completeness, here is a `data.table` solution (including data):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[, .(diff = difftime(max(time_answered), min(time_answered), unit = 'mins')), 
          by = submition_id]
```

> ```
>    submition_id           diff
> 1:            2 14.666667 mins
> 2:            4  1.966667 mins
> 3:            5 10.850000 mins
> ```

#### Data

> ```
> DT <- readr::read_table("submition_id       time_answered
>            2 2017-11-06 14:19:30
>            2 2017-11-06 14:22:45
>            2 2017-11-06 14:24:55
>            2 2017-11-06 14:34:10
>            4 2017-11-06 14:31:23
>            4 2017-11-06 14:33:21
>            5 2017-11-06 14:54:48
>            5 2017-11-06 14:59:38 
>            5 2017-11-06 15:05:39")
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
require(dplyr)
DF <- DF%>%group_by(submition_id)%>%summarise(difference = difftime(min(time_answered), max(time_answered), units = "min"))
```

Comment: @akrun I did't see the comment, most likely it was done at the same time

Comment: Check the closing parenthesis of `summarise` and maybe you don't need `ungroup` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The `lubridate` package is very useful, `interval` from`lubridate` will create a time span between specific times, you can then then calculate the `duration` of this time span, using `group_by` from `dplyr` and `arrange` ... can you supply some data example / dput as others have suggested to work with an extract of your data

Comment: Se if this works
             
structure(list(submition_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2", 
"4", "5"), class = "factor"), time_answered = structure(c(1509974370, 
1509974372, 1509974378, 1509974381, 1509975107, 1509975110, 1509975112, 1509975217, 1509975217, 1509975221, 
1509975226, 1509975229, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("submition_id", "time_answered"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))